# Where is the error in my code for getting user guesses?

Tags: python-3.x

My code only prints user_guesses: [2] when it should print user_guesses: [9, 5, 2]

This is the code I have so far.

```
num_guesses = int(input())
user_guesses = []
for i in range(num_guesses):
    guess = int(input())

user_guesses.append(guess)


print('user_guesses:', user_guesses)
```

Comment: `user_guesses.append(guess)` should be inside the `for` loop.

Answer (score 0):

Use append function in loop so that each value in guess is append to user_guesses

```
num_guesses = int(input())
user_guesses = []
for i in range(num_guesses):
    guess = int(input())
    user_guesses.append(guess)


print('user_guesses:', user_guesses)
```